# PNG images ok on simulator but don't display on device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My iphone app pulls in about 300 images from a bundle, and then on one of my view controllers it displays one at random.  This works fine on the simulator (xcode 4.3.3 / iphone 5.0 or 5.1 simulator) but not when I push it to my device (iphone 3gs).  The app runs and there are no errors on the log, but that part of the view where the image should be is just blank, like the color of the background.

Things I've tried:

1. I've checked and double-checked the case of the filenames vs
   references in code.
2. I checked the Build Phase called Copy Bundle
   Resources, and it's definitely set to copy the bundle to the device.
3. I looked at the log produced by the build, and although that was the first time I'd examined it in detail, it had no errors and seemed to be copying the bundle across.  Here's the snippet from the log:

   ```
   CpResource FlagQuiz/flagimages.bundle /Users/ian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlagQuiz-drrjrlxfifrmbnaissqfqxuixchb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FlagQuiz.app/flagimages.bundle
   cd /Users/ian/Documents/xcodeapps/FlagQuiz
   setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
   builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip /Users/ian/Documents/xcodeapps/FlagQuiz/FlagQuiz/flagimages.bundle /Users/ian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FlagQuiz-drrjrlxfifrmbnaissqfqxuixchb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FlagQuiz.app
   ```

Here's a screenshot of the bundle as requested: https://skitch.com/bobsmells/eeask/flagquiz.xcodeproj-afghanistan.png

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of a view images of the bundle?

Comment: Try using another PNG, make sure that there isn't a problem with the PNG you are attempting to use. I've seen that be the problem multiple times.

Comment: @Fab1n - Thanks, will do when I get home from work (don't have my mac here)

Comment: @Jeremy1026-It's all png files...around 300 of them. It's basically a flag quiz - not an original idea, more of a teach-me-iOS-programming exercise.  So after displaying 1 flag, the user chooses from 4 country names, it tells them right or wrong and then displays the next 1.  It does this 10 times each with a random image from the 300 png images, and none of the images display when it's on the iPhone. As for there being a problem with the png files, I guess it's possible that there's the same problem with all of them as they all came from the same place; I'll try with a few other random pngs.

Comment: @Fab1n I've put a link to a screenshot as requested - I hope that's what you were after.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why do you list them in the bundle. you don't need a bundle. Did you add the bundle to the target? And I hope you didn't add the files then, too. You only need to add the bundle

Comment: No, I only added the bundle.  What do you mean you don't need a bundle? I'm pretty green with iOS programming, and that's the only way I'd found to add the files - what other way is there?

Answer (score 4):

Issues have been known in the Xcode compression of PNG files. I personally submitted an App to the App Store that refused to be accepted because it had corrupted PNG files - which they were not. Turned out Xcode was corrupting them on build.

Maybe this is the same issue.

Go to Project -> Build Settings and try setting "Compress PNG Files" to NO.

Comment: This might of course make your app substantially bigger, givin' you say you have about 300 images.

Comment: yeah sorry I forgot to mention I'd found that solution mentioned and had already tried turning "Compress PNG Files" to NO, but it made no difference.

Comment: This worked for me, but you're right could potentially make app substantially larger.

Comment: Also remember that Mac OS X file system is case insensitive - whereas iOS file system is not.